# Border px issue

Tags: html, css

Currently I have a 1px border that wraps around each job title that I post. The issue that I have is that on the bottoms where i placed the red logo the 1 px's overlap making a thicker line (2px) than the rest. How can I fix this but still have a full border when each page is opened. Thanks for taking a look.

http://jobspark.ca/job-listings/

UPDATED CSS

```
article .post {
border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
border-top: none;
}

article.article-index-null .post,
article.article-index-1 .post {
border-top: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
}
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**
Only thing is now when you click and open a page "parts person" for example the top border is missing. http://jobspark.ca/job-listings/2013/6/3/wellsite-trailer-energy-services-technician

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the top border from each post except the first one:

```
article .post {
    border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
    border-top: none;
}
article .post:first-child {
    border-top: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
}
```

**Edit:**  Because your html structure has a series of `article` elements with one `.post` in each (instead of a series of `.post` elements inside an `article`, as I'd assumed), the above code won't work, but the principle is the same. You can't use `article:first-child` because there is another sibling element that is the first child, but since you have given the first article a specific class name, you can use that, as follows:

```
article .post {
    border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
    border-top: none;
}
article.article-index-1 .post {
    border-top: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
}
```

**Second Edit:** Since you are reusing the same html on for both item view and list view but don't want the top border removed in item view, do the following:

```
article .post {
    border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
}
.view-list article post {
    border-top: none;
}
.view-list article.article-index-1 .post {
    border-top: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
}
```

Alternatively, since in your unit view you have given the article the class "article-index-null" you could also do the following:

```
article .post {
    border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
    border-top: none;
}
article.article-index-null .post,
article.article-index-1 .post {
    border-top: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
}
```

Either one should work.

Comment: Didn't seem to work. I left the css in for you to see and updated the css above

Comment: It doesn't work because your HTML is different from what was implied. This is one reason one should always post *all* the relevant code. In your html, every `.post` will also be a `:first-child`.  The same principle applies, but you have to write the declaration to look for the first `article`.  Can't use `article:first-child` because a different element is the first child, but you have given that first article a specific class. Thus, instead of `article .post:first-child` use `article.article-index-1 .post` and it will work.

Comment: Thanks Derek that makes sense. Ill make sure to post more info next time. Only this is now when you open up one of the post it is missing the top border http://jobspark.ca/job-listings/2013/6/3/wellsite-trailer-energy-services-technician

Comment: Wow thanks Derek. I saved what you did in my book for future reference. Have a good day!

Comment: Hey Derek, can you see why the top border has disappeared http://jobspark.ca/job-listings/2013/7/10/service-technician  You will notice it if you look above the title "Service Technician". It is showing this for each page that I open

Comment: @ChrisS, if you inspect the style for that element, you would see that the border-top is set to 'none'.  You used the second of my suggested solutions from the second edit. Using the first one will probably fix this, but you have to test it sitewide.  I can't predict where you might be reusing these classes across your site, so you have to test carefully and make sure your CSS is specific enough to target precisely the elements you want and no more.

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
article .post {
  padding: 12px 16px;
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  border-bottom: none;
  background: white;
}
```

And add this:

```
article .post:last-child { 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this. i would wrap the entire articles section with a `<div>` that has only a 1px top border, no padding. then every article would only need left, right and bottom borders to achieve the look you are going for.

```
article .post {
padding: 12px 16px;
border-left: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
border-right: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
background: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using border what about using border-left border-right and border top ?
Seems like this is solving your issue.